# mvc3 jquery endless/infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, scroll

I am trying to figure out how to do an endless/infinite scroll using mvc3 and jquery and haven't gotten anything to work. I have a normal page that is loaded with data the first time you get on it and then as the user's scrolls down I attempt to call out my partialview and load 10 more rows of data.
This is the controller that I am trying to target to load 10 more rows of data

```
 public PartialViewResult feeds()
    {
          var iefeeds = sqlConnection.Query<thread>("Select top 10 * from threads"}).ToList();
         return PartialView("_maps", new homepage { threadings = iefeeds.ToList(), threader=smith   
    });
```

It is that simple that partialView loads 10 more rows of data from the database and it works because I have tested it. This is my Jquery to determine when to load the new data

```
  $(window).scroll(function ()
             {
                 if($(window).scrollTop== $(document).height() - $(window).height())
                 {

                     $.ajax({
                         type: "GET",
                         url: "Account/feeds"
                     });

                 }

                 });
```

and below on the page this is the foreach that I want to add on

```
   <div id="update">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
            {


            }
     </div>
```

So to recap the first time user's come to the page the **account/feeds** partialview is triggered automatically with 10 items and now I am trying to add 10 more items when the scrollbar hits the bottom of the window from that same partialview, any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: First: Is your ajax call being fired?  Use a console (Firebug, or built-in) to watch for the ajax call being fired.  Within the console, you can see both the *request* **and** what is returned, which is how you would troubleshoot this problem.  Second: Your ajax call does *not* send a "page" or "start" parameter.  How will your function know which additional feed items to grab?

Comment: I will look into firebug and troubleshoot as you suggested, I mainly got that code from an online youtube tutorial on infinite scrolls.